# Best way to send a simple digital signal wirelessly (close-range)?

Tags: wireless, digital-communications

I have a small device which powers two vibrating motors. I would like the vibrating motors to be wireless (ie, not actually connected to the device).

Here's some more info:

- Here's the vibrating motor: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8449
- I have the motors working in my circuit perfectly, I would just like the signal to be wireless. I'm currently running them off 3.3V I think.

Would something like this work: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12770?

This is all new to me so I'm unsure how to make it all work. Would it be something like this:

```
[Device][RFM12BSP] ----- air -----> [RFM12BSP][motor][coin battery]
```

The issue I have is that I'm not really sending data. I just want to send a simple digital signal (ie, turn motor on, turn motor off).

How would I implement this?

Comment: That could work really anything can work for just turning something on and off even just ripping the guts out of a cheap remote control toy car.

Comment: I'm very new to the wireless stuff. I'd like to keep the solution as small as possible. Am I looking at RF as the interface? From what I'm reading I need a decoder and stuff right?

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but if you're planning to turn on and off a motor this can be considered as data. From what i've learned, any signal is data. Oh and with the RF, did you mean a transmitter and receiver?

Answer (score 1):

Yes those RFM12BSP transceiver boards will work, but you will need a microcontroller on both sides of the link to send/receive the data from the transceivers SPI interface.

If there will always be an unobstructed line of sight between the device and motors, then it should be possible to construct something using infrared akin to a TV remote, with an IR Emitting diode and an IR receiver such as the TSOP4438. You will need to drive a 38kHz signal in to the LED from a microcontroller such as an arduino. The presence or absence of the 38kHz clock would produce a logic high/low on the motor side. The benefit to this would be a far simpler circuit on the motor side.